# How to track the completion of all the threads. C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion

I need to freeze the main thread until the end recursion.
Recursion depth = count of threads.

sample code:

```
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1;
    Random ran;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        method();
        label1.Text = "Threads is finished";
    }


    private void method() // recursive method
    {

            Thread.Sleep(100);

            backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

            backgroundWorker1.DoWork +=
                new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();               //Beginning new thread
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender,
       DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
            ran = new Random();
            Thread.Sleep(ran.Next(500, 1000));
            if (ran.Next(1, 5) != 1) // if = 1 then to stop recursion
            {
                method();
            }
    }
```

When the threads are completed, `label1.Text` must have the value `"Threads is finished"`. How is this done?

Comment: You are assigning a new "thread/worker" object instance to existing and single `backgroundWorker1` variable, not sure this is fine, at least this is not fine if you want wairing for all created threads, you have to have references to all created threads/workers instances

Comment: I believe this pattern is called a fork bomb, it doesn't scale well. Also as sll points out, those instance variables are not thread safe. Why not ask the question rather than presenting a solution you've got half way through? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx

Comment: The code is too silly, there's no point in starting a bgw repeatedly.  Just use one bgw and write a loop in DoWork.  Set the label in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Console application PoC which caches references to all created workers and uses numeric variable to check how many workers still in progress, when this value reaches 0 - application terminates. Please let me know in case of any questions.

```
class Program
{
    private static IList<BackgroundWorker> workers;
    private static Random ran;
    private static int activeWorkersCount;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        workers = new List<BackgroundWorker>();
        DoWork();

        while (activeWorkersCount > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for all workers to finish...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void DoWork() // recursive method
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        var newWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        newWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorkerDoWork;
        newWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, e) =>
               {
                  Console.WriteLine("[E] Worker finished");
                  Interlocked.Decrement(ref activeWorkersCount);
               };
        Interlocked.Increment(ref activeWorkersCount);
        newWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private static void BackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[S] Worker started");
        ran = new Random();
        Thread.Sleep(ran.Next(500, 1000));
        if (ran.Next(1, 5) != 1) // if = 1 then to stop recursion
        {
            DoWork();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done this way. 
while (activeWorkersCount > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
after the completion of the first thread while return false.
In this problem...
Speak in your own language if you will be comfortable. I'm Russian

Comment: Yes, create a thread can be dozens.  I need  get the message when finished all threads

Comment: When `if (activeWorkersCount > 0)` returns false this mean that no worker threads are scheduled

Comment: No, In this case, returns false when the first thread is finished.
I checked

Comment: In console application I've provided or in your? have you applied any changes to DoWork? If so pelase update a code or show how to reproduce this in console app I've provided

Answer (score 0):

When you decide it's time to stop recursion you can post a callback onto the GUI thread. Off the top of my head it'll be something like this:

```
if(ran.Next(1,5)!=1)
{
  method();
}
else
{
  Action action=()=>label1.Text = "Threads is finished";
  this.BeginInvoke(action);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a method to update Label1:

```
private void WorkFinished()
{
   if(Label1.InvokeRequired)
   {
      Label1.Invoke(WorkFinished);
   }
   else
   {
      Label1.Text = "Threads is finished";
   }
}
```

2) Call WorkFinished() from backgroundWorker1_DoWork.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CountDownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx) class:

Example:

```
using (CountDownEvent countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(numberOfThreads))
{
    for (int threadIndex= 0; i < numberOfThreads; threadIndex++)
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
            th =>
            {
                DoWork();
                countdownEvent.Signal();
            }, threadIndex);

    countdownEvent.Wait();
}
Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
```

Comment: `CountDownEvent` is not fit into this solution, I believe `numberOfThreads` is unknown and could be changed in runtime sicne it depends on a next randomly generated value, so each enw thread will call `random()` and it is possible that a new thread will be scheduled so you need incrementing `numberOfThreads` and this is not possible with `CDE`

Comment: CountDownEvent appears to support adding as well, so long as the count doesn't hit 0 (causing the event to be set). [CountDownEvent.AddCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321903.aspx)

Comment: @ChrisChilvers : thanks, makes sense. I've overlooked that, apologizes

Comment: As pointed out by @chris-chilvers the addition to countdown event can happen within the recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using a volatile integer number and it works well.

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1;     
    Random ran;
    long runningThreads = 0;
    public void Start()     
    {         
        method();         
       // Console.WriteLine("Threads is finished");     
    }       
    private void method() // recursive method     
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref runningThreads);
        Console.WriteLine("New thread started");
        Thread.Sleep(100);              
        backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();              
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork +=                 
            new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);             
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();               //Beginning new thread     
    }      
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender,        DoWorkEventArgs e)     
    {             
        ran = new Random();             
        Thread.Sleep(ran.Next(500, 1000));             
        if (ran.Next(1, 5) != 1) // if = 1 then to stop recursion             
        {                 
            method();             
        }
        Finished();
    }
    private void Finished()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref runningThreads);
        if (Interlocked.Read(ref runningThreads) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Threads is finished");     

        }
    }
```

Comment: Could lead to a situation where you the check for if(runningThreads == 0) precedes the increment runningThreads++. As you are not using a lock?

Comment: thats why i have taken volatile int

Comment: volatile keyword will ensure that you do not read a variable from cache, but does it guarantee avoiding a race condition here? For example check following steps: 1. Decrement running threads  2 Check for running threads == 0 and before console statement 3: Another thread kicks in execution and increments runningThreads, correct? That is the reason for using Interlocked increment, Interlocked decrement and CountDownEvent?